Name For a Two-Part Removable Mount Like a CB Radio Microphone Mount
What is the most proper name for a two-part mount like the one depicted below:

The left/below part is the fixed mount which acts as a receiver for the other part, and the right/above part is affixed to the object (not depicted, but would be in the foreground) to be mounted. If it's not obvious, the intent of such a mount is to be fairly stable but still removable.
Another fairly common example of this kind is the button dashboard mount for a CB radio microphone (I'm not providing pictures of this due to copyright concerns, but a search for "cb button mount" in a search engine will show you examples).
I've considered "hammerhead mortise and tenon" because that seems to be mechanically similar, but I've never found that name used for this kind of mount.
Awarding the answer to @Akriss, French Cleat or its synonym split batten are a close enough match.

While this looks like it could be 3D printed, how is this question related to 3D printing?

@agarza I deduce the point of your question is that neither the question or an answer enriches the craft of 3D printing.
I asked here because the question came up in the process of 3D printing for me, so someone else interested in 3D printing might know the answer. Wine-drinking isn't wine-making, but I might ask a wine aficionado a wine-making question.
Truth be told I'm not a frequent Stack Exchange user and I didn't see a more specific community than this. If you feel there's a more correct community (or Stack Overflow) for the question you could say that.

Please don't get me wrong, I am not trying to shoot down your question. But if any question that was even tangentially related were allowed on each site, then it would become more difficult to find a solution to a particular problem. There have to be some guidelines that have to be followed for the system to work efficiently for all. That being said, if you could phrase your question in a manner related to 3D printing it can remain open.

I do not see a way see a way to rephrase the question to make it specific to 3D printing, mods are welcome to close. So I can avoid this error again, should a question post to Stack Overflow if one can't find a directly-relevant community?

If you are unsure if a particular question is suitable for a site, I recommend asking on the Meta for that site.

I think the closest name would be "French Cleat".
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_cleat
Or possibly a "flush mount bracket"

Some plush-mount bracket designs are getting close, and I’ve since found V-lock brackets and dart board brackets that use the same principle. I was hoping for a more generic woodworking/fabrication term for this design.
